# Blocking web page in ASP.NET Web Forms with long running method

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, asynchronous, webforms

I want to show a database result in my GridView but the web page is extremly slow when calling a long running method.

Inside the GridView I have a template field with the following item template:

```
<ItemTemplate>  
        <asp:Label ID="lblNumResults" runat="server" Text='<%# GetNumCrawlResults(Convert.ToInt32(Eval("id"))) %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
```

This is the corresponding method:

```
public string GetNumCrawlResults(int jobId)
{
    var task = Task.Run(() => Utilities.GetNumCrawlResults(jobId));
    //this is slow and blocks the GUI
    return Convert.ToString(task.Result);
}
```

This is the database query:

```
public static async Task<int> GetNumCrawlResults(int jobId)
{
    DocumentCollection collection = await GetOrCreateCollectionAsync(database.SelfLink, Convert.ToString(jobId));

    var result = (from c in documentDb.CreateDocumentQuery<Shared.CrawlResult>(collection.SelfLink)
                  select c).AsEnumerable();
    return result.Count();
}
```

Is there any way to assign the label text when a async method has finished?

Thanks

Comment: How slow is slow? In any case, for async methods use need to use the `await` syntax. And for Web Forms, you need to mark the page as async and use `RegisterAsyncTask` as described [here](http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/performance-and-caching/using-asynchronous-methods-in-aspnet-45).

Comment: Is there no way you can get this count as part of your initial query? DataBinding is still in iterative event and calling a long running function on each iteration is a bad idea.

Comment: @mason Thanks. I have made a small example http://pastebin.com/Mw5rHN6P but it is still bocking the website load for 5 seconds. I am using .net 4.5

Comment: Let's get this clear: *any* code running in the code behind is going to block the page load, whether or not you're using async. That's how the ASP.NET model works: it only sends the response down once, so all code is blocking the response. If you want to send down the HTML for the page and then send down the data later, then you should instead switch to using AJAX on the client to load the information.

Answer (score -1):

Is your page rendering a result? I have the impression the task.wait() statement is missing.

Anyway, in your case I would use Ajax and Knockout (or similar).